# how to have a multiple command in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm a newbie and trying to make a simple progman that start cm.exe and then change its drive letter and change the attribute of all the files in that particular drive and delete all the .link files or the shortcut folders.

In cmd, the input is like this:

```
(Drive letter):
Attrib -r -s -a -h *.*
Del auto run.inf
Del *.lnk
```

How write this command in batch file. Thanks a lot (sorry for my English. Lol :3)

Comment: Maybe this thread could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118338/putting-multiple-commands-into-one-batch-file

Answer (score 1):

Use an editor line [Editplus](http://www.editplus.com/) or notepad++ to enter precisely those lines in a file named `whateveryoulike.BAT`. It's the `.BAT` part that does the trick. (You could also use `NOTEPAD` but be careful - you need to save as ANSI and NOTEPAD has a habit of attempting to format the text)

From the `CMD` prompt, type `PATH`. This will show a **<kbd>;</kbd>**-separated list of directories which is searched to try to find the command `whateveryoulike`. Save the `whateveryoulike.BAT` in any directory in that list.

Serious batchers will add a directory to contain batches and add that directory to the path.

Then all you need to do is issue the command `whateveryoulike` at the prompt, and the batch file will run - just as though you had manually entered the lines it contains.

It's traditional to add a line

```
@echo off
```

at the start of the file, which suppresses `ECHO`ing of the commands as they are executed.

It's also a good idea to add a

```
SETLOCAL
```

command after that, to automatically dispose of changes the batch may have made to the environment when the batch finishes. This is a matter of judgement, but problems can be caused by batches unexpectedly altering variables.

Finally, a batch can access parameters by using `%n` where n=1..9 so if you were to compose

```
@echo off
setlocal
set drive_letter=%1
%Drive_letter%:
Attrib -r -s -a -h *.*
Del auto run.inf
Del *.lnk
```

as `whateveryoulike.BAT` and save it in a directory on your `PATH` then, from the prompt

```
whateveryoulike e
```

would execute your series of commands and assign `e` as `drive_letter`. Note the method of accessing a variable - <kbd>%</kbd>variablename<kbd>%</kbd>

(but be careful!!!!!)

You would possibly prefer

```
@echo off
setlocal
set drive_letter=%1
if not defined drive_letter echo drive letter required&goto :eof
%Drive_letter%:
...
```

Which checks whether you actually specified a parameter. Note the use of <kbd>&</kbd> to separate commands on the same physical line and the label `:eof` (where the **<kbd>:</kbd>** is required) to mean `go to the end of the physical batchfile`

Finally - and be VERY, VERY careful with this - you can also use `DEL /s` to delete matching files in **ALL SUBDIRECTORIES** and `attrib /s` to change the attributes of matching files in **ALL SUBDIRECTORIES** (well, all subdirectories from the current, anyway...) - not for the faint-hearted!!

Comment: What kind of formatting does Notepad do on text? I've never encountered this before.

Comment: @gabe It can try to format to n columns, breaking long lines, drop or insert terminal spaces on lines, convert tabs to spaces and generally act like a cheap word-processor. Some people have no problems - it could come down to quite how you use it. Frankly, I've not used it in so long now I forget the precise details, but it can play havoc with batch files. Once bitten, twice shy.

Comment: I use Notepad daily and have never seen any of this. It does wrap at 1024 characters (but not insert newlines). I've never seen it damage any sort of text files.